# Sending an image/video using sockets and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My application requires a section for users to communicate each other. For this, I am using socket-io. For sending text(as strings). I use utf-8, which works perfectly.

However, when sending an image or a video on a socket, how do I approach this? Would I turn the image or the video into binary format, and send that on the socket?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an example about how to send your files with socket.io :

```
var fileReader = new FileReader(), 
    slice = file.slice(0, 100000); 

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(slice); 
fileReader.onload = (evt) => {
    var arrayBuffer = fileReader.result; 
    socket.emit('slice upload', { 
        name: file.name, 
        type: file.type, 
        size: file.size, 
        data: arrayBuffer 
    }); 
}
```

there is a full tutorial with example about send file with socket.io and receive it in the server nodeJs follow [this](https://medium.com/@Mewsse/file-upload-with-socket-io-9d2d1229494)

Comment: Yes bro it is a peer to peer

Comment: Is there another way for a peer-peer application, something more simpler?

Comment: @EesaMunir Yes there is you can use webRTC there is a framework who help you in your project  [peerjs](https://peerjs.com/) ... good luck

Comment: Thank you man. So does webRTC do all the binary reading and opening for you?

Comment: @EesaMunir yes it do, but if you want save the chat history i recommend that u do it with webSocket because when users send message it will be manipulating and saved on the Server(DataBase)... Good luck :)

Comment: Ah ok nice, however I'm a bit confused. Can you tell please me how webRTC helps reading and opening binary files my friend?

Comment: @EesaMunir there is a full example how to send file with webRTC in this [link](https://deepstreamhub.com/tutorials/protocols/webrtc-file-transfer/)...